# ms access date and time. Time must be 7:00 AM and user must not edit time

Tags: ms-access, datetime, date, time, automation

I have a form where users input information for a test run on a particular date.  This creates a table that i then link with another table based on the date and an ID.  In this other table (filled by a form created by someone else) all of the times are 7:00 AM.  Whoever created the form for that table did what I'm now asking about; since the dates must match EXACTLY in order for the tables to be joined, i need to do this, too.  The way I want to do this is to have two fields in my form.  One for the date (mm/dd/yyyy) and one for the time (##:##:## xM) and i want the time field to be uneditable by the user.  This way the user knows that he/she cannot edit the time.  So far i know how to do all this with input masks and such.  However, I don't know how to add these two fields together and then store that in the table.  Help?

Comment: If you want all date fields to have the same time, then you don't need to store the time part at all. Just store the Date() part (i.e., the integer value). If you're populating the fields with Now() change that to Date(). The point is that if all fields have the same time, you don't need to store it at all.

Comment: ...but don't format to add a Validation Rule or CHECK constraint to enforce the rule to ensure the problem doesn't reoccur.

Comment: i did need to store it.  There is another table that I am inner joining to this table on the date.  In the other table, the dates have already been stored with date and time and all of the times are 7AM.  It's silly, i know, but I didn't write the old table code and I can't change it.  I just have to live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a single Date/Time field in your form's record source, and you want to display the date portion in one form control and the time portion in another control.  And the time portion should always be 7:00 AM.

Add two text box controls (*txtDate* and *txtTime*) to your form which both use the same Date/Time field as their control source.  Set the `Format` property of *txtDate* to *Short Date*.  Set the `Format` property of txtTime to *Medium Time*.  Also, on the Data tab for *txtTime*, set Enabled to No and Locked to Yes.

Then, in the *After Update* event of *txtDate*, you can use:

```vb
Private Sub txtDate_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtDate.Value = DateValue(Me.txtDate.Value) + #7 AM#
End Sub
```

If you need to massage existing values in your table, you can use an `UPDATE` query:

```sql
UPDATE YourTable SET YourDateField = DateValue(YourDateField) + #07:00#
WHERE YourDateField IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write an update to set all the existing times to midnight (i.e. 00:00:00), and then alter the form so that it also truncates dates to midnight. The add a Validation Rule or `CHECK` constraint to ensure the values cannot be anything other than midnight. Then, if you are using user-level security, review the table privileges to ensure users cannot remove the Validation Rule or `CHECK` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

User a datetime picker control - let the user just pick the date portion. The time portion sits in another control - a Label or a locked Textbox.

When you write your SQL to update / insert into your table, you can simply add these two control values together as

```
Declare MyDateTimeValue as String
'This creates value of MM/DD/YYYY
MyDateTimeValue = MyDateTimePickerControl.Value 

'This adds a blankspace and HH:MM:SS to become "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"
MyDateTimeValue = MyDateTimeValue  + ' ' + MyTimeLabelControl.Value
```

Use the variable MyDateTimevalue in your SQL Statement as

```
DoCmd.ExecuteSQL ('Insert Into MyTable (Col1, DateTimeColumn) Values (1, #' & MyDatetimeValue & '#')
```